# pattern for parsing a logfile

Tags: php, parsing, design-patterns

I have a PHP 5.3.4 project where I need to parse a logfile and display a summary to the user. The logfile format (which is outside my control) looks roughly like this:

```
BEGIN GROUP: my group
<TESTCASE ID=1>
*** Test Name: Some Test
</TESTCASE RESULT="PASSED">
END GROUP: my group
BEGIN GROUP: another group
<TESTCASE ID=1>
*** Test Name: Some other Test
</TESTCASE RESULT="PASSED">
BEGIN GROUP: sub group
<TESTCASE ID=2>
*** Test Name: Foo
</TESTCASE RESULT="FAILED">
END GROUP: sub group
<TESTCASE ID=3>
*** Test Name: Bar
</TESTCASE RESULT="PASSED">
END GROUP: another group
```

I think I'd like to first parse the logfile in to a set of object like this:

```
abstract class ResultBase
{
    // name of this result element
    private $name_ = null;
    // line number in the result log corresponding ot this element
    private $line_ = null;

    // ...
}

// defines a Group element from the logfile
class Group extends ResultBase
{
    // array of ResultBase-derived child elements belonging to this group.
    private $children_ = null;

    // ...
}

// defines a TestCase element from the logfile
class TestCase extends ResultBase
{
    // test case id
    private $id_ = null;
    // "passed" or "failed" result
    private $result_ = null;

    // ...
}

class LogFile
{
    // array of ResultBase-derived elements that constitute the log
    private $elements_ = null;
}
```

And then print the objects:

```
function Print( $log_file )
{
    // some recursive print algorithm...
}
```

I am new to PHP, so if the above is the wrong direction to take this, please let me know.

I'm looking for some pattern to apply and some pseudo-code suggestion on how to implement it.

```
function Parse( $log_file_name )
{
    $logfile = new LogFile();
    // what goes here???
    return $logfile;
}

Print(Parse('C:\mylogfile.log'));
```

Comment: Before you start working on picking out the color of your wallpaper, make sure you have walls to begin with. Get the logic for parseing/extracting the logfile data going first, THEN decide what your object should look like.

Comment: It's at the bottom of the question, the "what goes here???" line. I probably should have put that on top. I welcome your suggestions on the parsing algorithm. Should the parser be some sort of state machine? (either in the TestCase state or Group state) What would that algorithm look like?

Comment: Exactly. You've put up a ton of useless fluff. We're not going to write a log parser for you.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking you to. I'm asking for some pseudocode and a direction. Not a working software product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
$log = new LogFile('C:\mylogfile.log');
$log->parse();
printf("Log has %d groups.\n", $log->getGroups()); # Log has 3 groups.
```

`LogFile` is just extending from [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/SplFileObject):

```
class LogFile extends SplFileObject {
    private $groups;
    public function rewind() {
        $this->groups = 0;
        parent::rewind();
    }
    public function current() {
        $line = parent::current();
        if (substr($line, 0, 13) === 'BEGIN GROUP: ') $this->groups++;
        return $line;
    }
    public function parse() {
        foreach($this as $line);
    }
    public function getGroups() {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

Maybe this gives you some pointers. A better variant would be a decorator that accepts any iterator so that it would make things even more flexible:

```
$log = new SplFileObject($logFileName);
$parser = new LogFileParser($log);
$parser->parse();
printf("Log has %d groups.\n", $parser->getGroups());

class LogFileParser extends IteratorIterator
{
    private $groups;
    public function rewind() {
        $this->groups = 0;
        parent::rewind();
    }
    public function current() {
        $line = parent::current();
        if (substr($line, 0, 13) === 'BEGIN GROUP: ') $this->groups++;
        return $line;
    }
    public function parse() {
        foreach($this as $line);
    }
    public function getGroups() {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the direction.